# Print only vowels from string from textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use two for loops and use `charAt` so if I put in "Banana" in the text box it will only show "aaa"

> `#textbox` = textbox
>
> `#lbl` = label (where the result will show)

This is what I have, and it's not working correctly...

```
$("#vow").click(function () {
    var vowels = "aeiou";
    var v = $("#textbox").val();
    var label = $("#lbl").html(v);

    for (i = 0; i < vowels.length; i++) {
        vowels.charAt(i) == v.charAt(j);
        for (j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
            label = v;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Simple" code (at least to read):

```
var vowels = "aeiou";
var label = "banana";

var stripped = "";
for (i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
  if(vowels.indexOf(label[i]) >= 0) stripped += label[i];
}
console.log(stripped);
```

But I advice you to simply use :

```
"banana".replace(/[^aeiouy]/ig, "")
```

I is a **regex** that says: "*replace everything that is not one of `aeiouy` to nothing*". i and g are **flags**: `i` = case insensitive, `g` = global (replace all occurrences)

Answer (score 2):

> Use [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over [**`String#split`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and then [**`Array#join`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it !

```js
var v = 'aeiou';
var input = 'Banana';
var splitted = v.split('');
var op = input.split('').filter(function(item) {
  return splitted.indexOf(item) > -1;
}).join('');
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function isVowel(c) {
     return ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].indexOf(c.toLowerCase()) !== -1
 }

 function getVowels(input) {
     var result = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
         if (isVowel(input.charAt(i))) {
             result = result.concat(input.charAt(i) + "");
         }
     }
     return result;
 }


 $("#vow").click(function() {
     var input = $("#textbox").val();
     $("#outputBox").val(getVowels(input));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="textbox" />
<button id="vow">Get Vowels</button><output id="outputBox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `replace` function

```js
$("#vow").click(function () {
    var v = $("#textbox").val();
    $("#vowels").html($("#textbox").val().replace(/[^aeiou]/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="textbox" />
<button id="vow">Get Vowels</button>

<p id="vowels"></p>
```